# How to prevent a specific element from having the same styling as other elements

Tags: html, css

The CSS for my blog's template gives all images a rounded border around them, along with a few other changes:

```
article img {
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.5em solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Some images, I don't want this border applied to. Right now, I have code which "resets" these settings before applying the actual settings i want:

```
img.smiley 
{
    /* RESET */
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 0px none;

    /* ACTUAL STYLE */
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

It works for now, but if the template's creator makes any changes to the template, it will break my images, and I will need to add more data to the "reset" section.

Is there any better way of doing this; perhaps some way of saying *"Let the `smiley` class ignore everything it knows about `img`, and only use this style instead"*?

Comment: You can use the `!important` clause

Comment: How about [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)?

Comment: @JoshC If you can think of a better title, feel free to edit the question; I was having difficulties thinking of one (or even knowing which words to search Google for). I was tempted for the sake of comedy to name it _Forget everything you know about CSS!_, but I felt that would be far too misleading.

Comment: @karthikr How would `!important` be applicable in this situation? I would still need to know which styles were used when I override them. Also, my own CSS is loaded in _after_ the template's.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:not` selector to define the initial styling. This will apply the styling to all `img` elements except those with the class `.smiley`... `img:not(.smiley)`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2rpTr/) demonstrating this

```
article img:not(.smiley) {
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.5em solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: The downside is, this would require me editing the theme's CSS (and remembering to keep that part edited even when the theme updates). But it's a good solution, and definitely doable in my current project.

Comment: @IQAndreas I could write some JS that would automatically insert something..? Would that be doable, since it wouldn't require you to manually update it? I am pretty sure you could put some JS somewhere that wouldn't be altered on the update. Let me know.